# When a user click a link sent to his email. a record from the database is deleted

Tags: javascript, php

The scenario : the user enter and order. 
A confirmation email is sent with a link to cancel the order. 
I would like to cancel the order by just clicking on the link without the user doing any other operation. is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Link in the email doesn't differ from any other link.

Comment: @user4035 i know that but how can i do the action when the user click on the link. deleting its uniqure record from the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and here's how you do it. Let's say the following link is the one you sent to his/her email

```
http://www.example.com/?orderId=12567544356&cancel=1
```

In your PHP code,

```
if(isset($_GET['cancel']) && isset($_GET['orderId']))
{
  //you may also want to check the values..
  //then delete the record from the database table ..
}
```

[Edit]
The order Id can be any value that you want to send as an email. For example,your code before sending the email might look like the following

```
$query = "SELECT orderId FROM Order WHERE user_id = $current_user_id";
// ... you will run the query
$orderId = $row['orderId'];
// then when you send your email, you will prepare the link the following way
$cancelOrderLink = "http://www.example.com/?orderId=$orderId&cancel=1";
// send it
```

Comment: can i send somevalue as a php variable for example 
$variable = "hello world";
and the link be like that:
http://www.example.com/?someVariable=$variable

Comment: So yes you can. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you have to send the url (link) of an ajax call in your email containing the id of order .The ajax call will make the change in your db.

For example in laravel I can write an ajax call in my routes file like this:

```
Route::get('/ajax-city', function() {
  $countryId = Input::get('CountryId');
  $city = City::where('country_id', '=', $countryId)->get();
  return Response::json($city);
});
```

Now I can simply call this:

http://website.com/ajax-city/2

Comment: The url of an ajax call? That is not possible. Ajax stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. No Ajax involved from a link. Also you do not want to present JSON to a user that cancels an order